# Variant Generating Function related to Euler Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

The generating function
$$\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}=\sum_{n\ge 0}E_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
counts the number of alternating permutations of a set with an even number of elements.  My question is this, if we alter the denominator slightly:
$$\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1+2x}=\sum_{n\ge 0}E_{2,k}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
what would this particular variant generating function count exactly?  What effect does the addition of $2x$ do to the number of alternating permuations of a set of elements?  How can I intuitively "see" what this functions counts (if anything)?

Comment: Where did you get your original series from? I just found that it also alternates.

Comment: What was the source of the variant series, and is there any reason behind specifically the '2' in the '2x' factor? It seems unlikely that the coefficients of that series would have any particularly clean form...

Comment: The reason for the $2x$ is, if we expand $e^{2x}$, we get $1+2x+4x^2/2!+8x^3/3!+...$.  It is just something I am interested in.

Comment: @john_leo, the original series is that of [Euler Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number).  $$\frac{1}{\cosh{x}}=\frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{2e^x}{(e^x+e^{-x})e^x}=\frac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+1}$$

Comment: You must be careful. Those numbers are strongly related to the number of alternating permutations, but strictly speaking, the alternating permutations are not counted by $1/\cosh(x)$ (as gf may not have neg. coefficients). Best re-read wikipedia's article on alternating permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best do a series expansion around $x=0$. In your case, your favorite computer algebra system yields:
$$
 \frac{2 e^x}{e^{2x}+1+2x} = 1-x+3/2 \cdot x^2 -5/2 \cdot x^3+ 31/8 \cdot x^4+ O(x^5)
$$
This is before multiplying each coefficient by $n!$.
Since the series is alternating, I don't think it actually "counts" anything. Maybe the sum of this series and another has a meaning.
Btw, had all coefficients been positive, the next step would have been to search for an entry in [OEIS](http://www.oeis.org).

Comment: I'm using the exponential generating functions, so my sequence is $1,-1,3,-15,93,-725,...$

Comment: I know, yet I don't know of a series with negative coefficients that "counts" something.

Comment: That was my confusion with the Euler Numbers (check the link above).  It definitely says on the Wikipedia page that they count what I mentioned above.  Perhaps if it were unsigned....

Comment: And those numbers definitely don't appear in the OEIS anywhere.

Comment: Related, not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I will reread the article on alternating permutations when I get a moment.